# Search all layers for single attribute in ArcMap without using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have 34 shapefiles loaded into my ArcMap. Each shapefile has only 1 attribute "ID" and each value is unique. Each feature in each shapefile is a polygon and there are approximately 17 billion polygons.

Is there a tool to search for an attribute and return which shapefile it is in?

I will use this many times (not for a single search use). I do not look for arcpy solution.

Comment: You should not work with shapefiles if you have such large datasets. Convert them to features in a file geodatabase and get much better performance

Comment: @BERA For directly working in a GIS application, yes I agree. However I am really only doing a 1 time use case to extract the data using `pyshp` to store in files for a  program to reference. Never going to use the shapefiles again after the first reading.

Comment: ArcPy is not separable from ArcGIS. It makes no sense to request an ArcGIS programming solution without arcpy. You have effectively eliminated ***all*** your keywords in comments, which means the question needs to be edited.

Comment: @Vince Just because I use ArcGIS for display purposes does not require me to use its overly cumbersome ArcPy. I'd rather work with the raw binary of the ESRI Shapefile spec then play with it.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you're in conformance with the shapefile spec, since 500m polygons is ***way*** larger than 2Gb (upwards of 56Gb, in fact, if I still have the spec memorized correctly), and any uniqueID in dBase would also exceed 2Gb (probably over 4Gb). I certainly can't force you to use ArcGIS,  but it would be useful if you remove the unrelated tags and add some new ones which are related.

Comment: I dont think there is a tool for this. This is best done with arcpy, and it is not difficult to do so.

Comment: @Vince 17 billion polygons each occupying 0.0125 in area. I've got a valid file that opens just fine in ArcGIS. 2.15GB.

Comment: NOT possible.  The shapefile specification (page 10) states that the storage required for a polygon is 44+4*numParts+16*numPoints (plus 8 bytes for the record header, page 5) For the minimum possible polygon (a triangle, with one part, and four vertices), the bytes/feature is 120. Seventeen *billion* triangles would require 2040 gigabytes (plus 100 bytes for each file header).  The maximum number of conformant features in a shapefile would be (2^31-2-100)/12 = 178,956,962 nil shapes. If your file is valid, it's because the writer stopped writing, leaving hundreds of millions of shapes out.

Comment: @Vince Nope. All 17 billion are there. Every square inch of the globe is covered as it should be for my purpose. But thanks for your input.

Comment: Last try: Thirty-four 2.1Gb shapefiles can store, at most, 3.58% of 17 billion rows of triangles (3.16% of 17B quadrilaterals), which means that 96+% of your ID queries will return no file.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps try Batch Select Layer by Attribute, input your layers with your expression.

Could probably do this in ModelBuilder too. If you need to keep changing the selection, iterate over your layers, and change the expression in the Select Layer by Attribute tool whenever you need.

That would select the shapefiles. In your Table of Contents, look in the List by Selection window for selected shapefiles

Answer (score 3):

This is straightforward with arcpy.  You can open the Geoprocessing -> Python window, copy and paste in the following code, and simply replace the bracketed "type ID value here" with whatever unique number you are searching for.  This will print in the Python window a list of any and all layers that have that unique ID.  Note: if you have more than one data frames, you will need to specify which one has the shapefiles you are querying.  If that's the case this can be modified slightly to accommodate:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
layers_with_id = []
for layer in layers:
    expression = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(layer, "ID") + ' = [your id here]'
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, "ID", where_clause=expression) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == [your ID here]:
                print layer.name
                layers_with_id.append(layer.name)

print "The following layers have that unique ID:"
for a in layers_with_id:
    print a
```

Comment: This operation is O(n) at worst. I don't really desire a solution that will require 17 billion operations. Nor one that uses arcpy.

Comment: You'll probably be hard-pressed to find a tool that wouldn't be using an operation such as this in the background, in ArcMap anyway (to my knowledge there isn't such a tool, in any event).  If you don't have the latitude to wait for such a query operation, your other option is to convert your shapes to tables.  Those could be searched at a higher order and even with 17 billion features not a lot of time would be involved.  However, if you simply want a tool that's already set up to do that you might be stuck.

Comment: Press binocular tool, enter you I'd and take vacation, unless you are going to use script above. I strongly suggest thought to replace cursor to da.searchcursor which is much faster. Another modification of the script is using query in cursor, e.g. first 2 letters.

Comment: @FelixIP good suggestion, this is included.  By the way this is actually O(n^2), so yes not ideal but again unless you run a batch process or run multiple iterations on your tables outside of Arc this is a straightforward option.

Comment: @AlecZ No, a worst case simple search of *n* rows is O( *n* ), not O( *n* -squared). Realistically, and assuming sanity on the part of the admin, the actualy "big-O" value would be *m* tables times baseX-log( *n* / *m* ), where X correlates to the number of keys kept in the index pages for the queries'  tables.

Comment: But in this instance, it's n rows times m iterations, isn't it?  The worst case complexity increases exponentially with additional feature classes (and associated rows).

Comment: No, not exponential, and the operation is distributed across a fraction of the total number of features -- n/m * m = n. The operation is "find the rows with ID id " (with 17 billion 4-byte integers, there **will** be duplicates). Without indexes, that's O(n). With indexes, it's dependent on the index efficiency, which in turn is dependent on index algorithm (likely to be B/B+/B* tree), page size, key size, and packing efficiency.

Comment: That's really interesting!  Does the "duplicates" you mention refer to the object values being stored in the same block?

Comment: This example is awful because you fail to use the `where_clause` parameter, which would permit an index to be used. I recommend using the canonical `with` syntax instead of using `del`